# Unable to view Recent changes post in new tab on iOS Firefox

Tags: bug, mobile-web, ios, mobile-firefox

As of right now, I am unable to view [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) in a new tab.

This is on Firefox on iOS 16.6.1 on an iPhone 12 Mini.

Hovering over the link gives me a correctly rendered preview of the question, but actually attempting to open the page in a new tab leaves it forever in a "loading" state with an empty white page in the viewport.

Manually creating a new tab and copy/pasting the URL of the page works fine. Similarly, viewing this question and clicking on the link to view it in the current tab works fine.

One of the answers was recently edited; [this is the latest change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/99024/revisions).

Comment: I don't get this problem, but in general, Firefox sometimes refuses to reload a *particular* page, even in a new tab (this behaviour started 1-2 years ago). The only way I know to fix it is to restart Firefox (desktop Linux. *A* current version there is 107.0.1 (it force updated yesterday)).